# Firebase authentication with Yahoo on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, yahoo-api

Using firebase authentication with Yahoo and followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/yahoo-oauth). So I created an App in Yahoo Developer with persmissions to read Contacts and Profile (Not sure which api to get the email and name so I requested for both)  and copied the Client Id and Secret in Firebase Authentication Sign In Method for Yahoo. Copied the Callback back to Yahoo Developer.

I followed the codes from the Firebase Authentication for Yahoo but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                signInWithOtherProvider(
                        OAuthProvider.newBuilder("yahoo.com")
                                .addCustomParameter("prompt", "login")
                                .setScopes(new ArrayList<String>() {
                                    {
                                        // Request access to Yahoo Mail API.
                                        add("mail-r");
                                        // This must be preconfigured in the app's API permissions.
                                        add("sdct-w");
                                        // Profile
                                        add("sdps-r");
                                    }
                                })
                                .build()
                );
}

private void signInWithOtherProvider(OAuthProvider provider) {
    Task<AuthResult> pendingTaskResult = auth.getPendingAuthResult();

    if (pendingTaskResult != null) {
        pendingTaskResult
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        signInSuccess(authResult);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        signInFailed(e);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        auth
                .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(getActivity(), provider)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        signInSuccess(authResult);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        signInFailed(e);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Has anyone successfully use Yahoo with Firebase on Android?

Appreaciate any help.

**UPDATE 2019/09/30**

I was able to replicate the error using Postman.

[image]

It seems that when I entered the incorrect callback URL in Yahoo Developer page, I got the same error. But when I entered it correctly (https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback), it went through. So my best guess is that it must be an issue with the callback url in Firebase.

Now looking at the Firebase console specifically in the Sign In Method for Yahoo, the callback url is (project-id.firebaseapp.com). Yahoo does not accept this as it seems to need a valid url so I added https://. So the redirect url I used is https://project-id.firebasapp.com. However, this still does not work. Then I tried the format similar to the other providers callback which is https://project-id.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler but still does not work.

Is there anything I can do in the Firebase Console to validate the callback url?

Comment: If you have a very general question such as "Has anyone successfully use Yahoo with Firebase on Android?" then I would suggest using a message board such as Reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: Any update? I think is the scope "mail-r" fault. Without the scopes the login works. I don't know what yahoo requires to get the email. I included all the permissions but still no success.

Comment: @4bottiglie Unfortunately i have not found any solution for this and just decided not to use Yahoo sign in.